# Using drizzle orm schemaFilter= deletes the schema

Tags: postgresql, drizzle

I've tried to specify the schema in my connection string `dbCredentials: { connectionString: "postgresql://postgres:pwd@localhost:5432/drizzle?schema=manytomany"}` ,but it does not work.  So I've tried using `schemaFilter` but I found that my schema got deleted instead.

```
import type { Config
} from "drizzle-kit";
 
export default {
  schema: "./src/db/schemas/schema.m2m.ts",
  out: "./drizzle",
  driver: 'pg',
  dbCredentials: { connectionString: "postgresql://postgres:pwd@localhost:5432/drizzle"},
  schemaFilter: 'manytomany',
  verbose:true
} satisfies Config;
```

Result:

```
Warning  You are about to execute current statements:

DROP SCHEMA "manytomany";
```

What is the correct way to connect to the non-public schema using drizzle and postgres ?

Thanks.

Comment: You **do not** connect to a schema, you just connect to the database. From there you can use `set search_path = <schema list>` or `set schema <schema list>`. See documentation [SET](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-set.html). Alternately, you can schema qualify db objects. For example `manytomany.table_name`.

Comment: @Belayer Thanks for your reply.  According to https://orm.drizzle.team/kit-docs/config-reference, it does say that it's possible to connect to a schema in config for push using schemaFilter ( and the database quoted is Postgresql )  Or I misunderstood ?  Anyone can help clarify ?  Thanks.

Comment: @Belayer I used set search_path = <schema list> when using PSQL.  How to specify this in the Drizzle schema definition ?

Comment: I do not use and have no idea about Drizzle. Sorry.